# How to optimize this query for (OpenStreetMap) map tiles rendering?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query, rendering, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my OpenStreetMap map tiles rendering.

This is one of the queries renderd makes to PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary("way") AS geom,
       "type"
FROM
  (SELECT way,
          way_area AS area,
          COALESCE(landuse, leisure, "natural", highway, amenity, tourism) AS TYPE
   FROM planet_osm_polygon
   WHERE way_area > 100000
   ORDER BY way_area DESC) AS DATA
WHERE "way" && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(-626172.1357124988 -626172.1357125007,10644926.3071125 10644926.30711249)'::box3d, 900913)
```

This is a result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
                                                                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on data  (cost=12419561.95..12504420.70 rows=5657250 width=249) (actual time=426086.657..494431.204 rows=5359537 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=12419561.95..12433705.08 rows=5657250 width=270) (actual time=425901.123..429052.490 rows=5359537 loops=1)
         Sort Key: planet_osm_polygon.way_area DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5134488kB
         ->  Seq Scan on planet_osm_polygon  (cost=0.00..9638717.64 rows=5657250 width=270) (actual time=1.714..353664.879 rows=5359537 loops=1)
               Filter: ((way_area > '100000'::double precision) AND (way && '010300002031BF0D000100000005000000D01B7C45F81B23C1E01B7C45F81B23C1D01B7C45F81B23C193DDD3C9B74D644198DDD3C9B74D644193DDD3C9B74D644198DDD3C9B74D6441E01B7C45F81B23C1D01B7C45F81B23C1E01B7C45F81B23C1'::geometry))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 183821045
 Planning time: 15.584 ms
 Execution time: 495248.135 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: try: run `VACUUM ANALYZE planet_osm_polygon`; add an (*btree*) index on `way_area`; also, use `BOX2D` (why 3D?)

Comment: did you get some better results?

Comment: How to change `BOX3D` to `BOX2D`? This is somehow defined in OSM style?

Comment: no, that's a PostGIS specific *bbox* type for the usage with *bbox* comparisons; not sure if you can alter *renderd*s standard queries (or did you write it?), though, and it's not important. the index I mentioned, however, is; if not in place, add it as I described, and run `VACUUM ANALYZE planet_osm_polygon`.

Comment: I haven't worked with *renderd/tirex* much, but I guess those are standard queries defined in the framework; if you can alter those, use the one I suggested, if not, DB tuning is what you're left with, and an index would speed up things in the scope of this qiestion.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment:

- Add index on `way_area`:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX planet_osm_polygon_way_area_idx
    ON planet_osm_polygon (way_area);
  ```
- update table stats:

  ```
  VACUUM ANALYZE planet_osm_polygon;
  ```
- run a simplified

  ```
  SELECT ST_AsBinary(way) AS geom,
         COALESCE(landuse, "natural", highway, amenity, tourism) AS "type"
  FROM planet_osm_polygon
  WHERE way && ST_SetSRID('BOX2D(-626172.1357124988 -626172.1357125007,10644926.3071125 10644926.30711249)'::box2d, 900913)
    AND way_area > 100000
  ```

Runs about three times faster with index, according to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, on my setup.

Note that adding another index, however, would only really be worth it if you run this over and over again; indexes have a significant footprint on disk and large indexes might have an impact on overall cluster performance.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following indexes:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX idx_poly_idlanduse ON planet_osm_polygon USING gist (way) WHERE((landuse IS NOT NULL) OR (leisure IS NOT NULL) OR (aeroway = ANY ('{apron,aerodrome}'::text[])) OR (amenity = ANY ('{parking,university,college,school,hospital,kindergarten,grave_yard}'::text[])) OR (military = ANY ('{barracks,danger_area}'::text[])) OR ('natural' = ANY ('{field,beach,desert,heath,mud,grassland,wood,sand,scrub}'::text[])) OR (power = ANY ('{station,sub_station,generator}'::text[])) OR (tourism = ANY ('{attraction,camp_site,caravan_site,picnic_site,zoo}'::text[])) OR (highway = ANY ('{services,rest_area}'::text[])));\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"planet_osm_polygon_nobuilding_index\" ON \"planet_osm_polygon\" USING gist (\"way\") WHERE \"building\" IS NULL;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX ferry_idx ON planet_osm_line USING gist (way) WHERE (route = 'ferry'::text);\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_aeroway\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"aeroway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_historic\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"historic\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_leisure\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"leisure\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_man_made\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"man_made\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_military\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"military\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_power\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"power\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_landuse\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"landuse\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_amenity\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"amenity\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_natural\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE 'natural' IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_highway\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"highway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_tourism\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"tourism\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_building\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"building\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_barrier\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"barrier\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_railway\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"railway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_aerialway\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"aerialway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_poly_power_source\" on planet_osm_polygon  USING gist (way) WHERE \"power_source\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_aerialway\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"aerialway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_waterway\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"waterway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_bridge\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"bridge\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_tunnel\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"tunnel\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_access\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"access\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_railway\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"railway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_power\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"power\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_name\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"name\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_ref\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) WHERE \"ref\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_aerialway\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"aerialway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_power_source\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"power_source\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_shop\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"shop\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_place\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"place\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_barrier\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"barrier\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_railway\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"railway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_amenity\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"amenity\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_natural\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE 'natural' IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_highway\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"highway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_tourism\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"tourism\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_power\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"power\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_aeroway\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"aeroway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_historic\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"historic\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_leisure\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"leisure\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_man_made\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"man_made\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_waterway\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"waterway\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_capital\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"capital\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_lock\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"lock\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"   \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_landuse\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"landuse\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis"  \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_point_military\" on planet_osm_point  USING gist (way) WHERE \"military\" IS NOT NULL ;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX idx_poly_wayarea_text ON  planet_osm_polygon USING gist (way) WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND place IS NULL AND way_area <= 320000;\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX \"idx_line_cutline\" on planet_osm_line  USING gist (way) where man_made='cutline';\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX idx_poly_buildings_lz ON planet_osm_polygon USING gist (way) where railway='station' or building in ('station','supermarket') or amenity='place_of_worship';\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX idx_poly_buildings ON planet_osm_polygon USING gist (way) where (building is not null and building not in ('no','station','supermarket','planned') and (railway is null or railway != 'station') and (amenity is null or amenity != 'place_of_worship')) or aeroway = 'terminal';\" -d gis" \
&& su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE INDEX water_areas_idx ON planet_osm_polygon USING gist (way) WHERE (((waterway IS NOT NULL) OR (landuse = ANY (ARRAY['reservoir'::text, 'water'::text, 'basin'::text]))) OR ('natural' IS NOT NULL));\" -d gis" \
```

Based on: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Species/PostGIS_Tuning

I can see a significant improvement. Previously, a map view rendered for a few minutes. Now it's down to tens of seconds.